# How can I add an image to ports?

Tags: jointjs

I've tried to add an image to rectangle port with JointJS, check my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blablabla/cjxyerow/95/) project. I need 2 images, one in my rectangle shape, I did that and one inside shape port. I don't know why, but when I  add `<image/>` tag in "portMarkup" somehow that duplicates first image (that one from my rectangle shape)..... I don't need that, I need 2 distinct images. Someone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSFiddle you don't differentiate between image attributes. When you make the instance of your shape `hmi = new joint.shapes.devs.Model`, the `image` attributes here override the image attributes when you defined `joint.shapes.devs.Model` in the first place.

If you comment out the following in the instance, you will see both images become links, and much smaller.

```js
image: {
     'xlink:href': "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/electronics-139/56/rj45__connector__Ethernet__port__connection-512.png", 
     width: 83,
     height: 68,
     'ref-x': .5,
     'ref-y': .5,
     ref: 'rect',
     'x-alignment': 'middle',
     'y-alignment': 'middle',
     id: 'hmi_image_ID_'
}
```

When you define `joint.shapes.devs.Model`, you could add a class to the image in portsMarkup, and then use that class in the attributes. That will make the image in the portsMarkup unique.

```js
portMarkup: '<g class="port port<%= id %>"><circle id="hmi_circle" class="port-body" style="stroke: #338264; fill: #6DC0A0; fill-opacity: 1;"/><text class="port-label"/><image class="port-image"/></g>',,
---------------
'.port-body': {
        r: 15,
        magnet: true,
        stroke: '#338264'
},
'.port-image': {
        href: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
},
```

This doesn't solve the issue that all the image attributes in the instance override the image attributes in the definition, so you will have to rearrange some code I guess.

Also, in JointJS the `devs` shape is deprecated, and it's not the recommended way to create ports now. [This tutorial](https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/ports) explains how to create ports with the PORT API in JointJS.

To create a Port with an image in JointJS now, you should create something like the following port definition.

```js
    const port = {
        label: {
            position: {
                name: 'left'
            },
            markup: [{
                tagName: 'text',
                selector: 'label'
            }]
        },
        attrs: { 
            portBody: { 
                magnet: true,
                width: 16,
                height: 16,
                x: -8,
                y: -8,
                fill:  '#03071E',
                stroke: 'none'
            },
            imgSrc: {
                width: 16,
                height: 16,
                x: -8,
                y: -8,
                href: 'https://via.placeholder.com/16.png/09f/fff'
            }, 
            label: { 
                text: 'port' 
            }
        },
        markup: [{
            tagName: 'rect',
            selector: 'portBody'
        }, {
            tagName: 'image',
            selector: 'imgSrc'
        }]
    };
```